# Nuget throws "Could not find a part of the path" error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, nuget

I have a VB.NET solution in Visual Studio 2013. I am using Nuget v2.12.0.817 (this is the lastest version available for Visual Studio 2013).

When I compile the solution I get an error that says:

> Could not find a part of the path

I googled and it seems it is a problem with Nuget. I have done what was explained [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/390075/nuget-could-not-find-a-part-of-the-path.html) as a workaround but without success. It consists on changing the space after $(SolutionDir) to a backslash in nuget.targets. My nuget.targets is as below:

```xml
<PaddedSolutionDir Condition=" '$(OS)' == 'Windows_NT'">"$(SolutionDir) "</PaddedSolutionDir> 
<PaddedSolutionDir Condition=" '$(OS)' != 'Windows_NT' ">"$(SolutionDir)"</PaddedSolutionDir>
```

Also, I have tried to change the 2 lines above to:

```xml
<PaddedSolutionDir Condition=" '$(OS)' == 'Windows_NT' and HasTrailingSlash('$(SolutionDir)')">"$(SolutionDir)\"</PaddedSolutionDir>
<PaddedSolutionDir Condition=" '$(OS)' == 'Windows_NT' and !HasTrailingSlash('$(SolutionDir)')">"$(SolutionDir)"</PaddedSolutionDir>
<PaddedSolutionDir Condition=" '$(OS)' != 'Windows_NT' ">"$(SolutionDir)"</PaddedSolutionDir>
```

But Nuget continues adding a blank space at the end of the path and it does not work... Any ideas?

**UPDATE 25/11/2019**:
I updated VS 2013 to Update 5 some days ago and suddenly it started compiling correctly. Today I have compiled the solution again, and now again the error still continues appearing. I have installed Nuget 2.12.0.817 (the last available for VS2013). I do not understand anything...

Comment: Have you installed [Visual Studio 2013 Update 5](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2829760/overview-of-visual-studio-2013-updates)? Have you updated NuGet `v2.12.0.X` to [`2.12.1`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.Build/2.12.1)?

Comment: @Jimi I tried to update Nuget to the last version through Visual Studio Gallery but it does not appear the update button for Nuget package so I cannot update from Gallery so I open a Nuget Package Manager Console and type this: Install-Package NuGet.Build -Version 2.12.1 Regarding to Visual Studio 2013 update 5, how can I know if it is installed on my system?

Comment: `Visual Studio -> Help -> About...`, second line (`Version...`). In the third line, you should see `2015` as the year of release.

Comment: @Jimi I hadn't updated Visual Studio 2013 to Update 5. Now I have just updated it and It works. No need to update Nuget to v2.12.1. I have the latest Nuget version for VS 2013 that is  2.12.0.817. However, by curiosity, how can I update Nuget to v2.12.1 for VS 2013? I have tried to update it through Nuget console by typing:Install-Package NuGet.Build -Version 2.12.1 . Installation completes correctly but once open Nuget console again it says version still is 2.12.0.817. Also I cannot update Nuget to last version from VS Gallery, no update button is available.

Comment: The supported method to update VS's NuGet Package Manager is through `Tools -> Extension and Updates -> Updates`. If your NyGet Package Manager is already updated, you don't need to install version-specific fixes. These are already included in the VS Update. All available distributions are listed here: [Available NuGet Distribution Versions](https://www.nuget.org/downloads).

Comment: @Jimi Today I have opened my solution and again I receive the same error. My VS 2013 is updated to Update 5 and I have the latest version of Nuget for VS2013, that is, 2.12.0.817. Why some days ago was working and now not? Any ideas?